# Requesting data from asp.cs thorugh ajax not working properly?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I'm learning asp.net as of now I'm trying to access the server data and assign the data to a textbox.

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


        }
        [WebMethod]
        public string GetStringValue()
        {
            return Environment.UserName;
        }

    }
```

webform1.aspx.cs :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class='col-sm-3'>
      <label >Username</label>
      <input id="username"  class="form-control input-sm" >
    </div>
    </div>

   <script type="text/javascript">

             $(document).ready(function () {
                 function getEmployees() {
                     $.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                         url: 'WebForm1.aspx/GetStringValue',

                         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                         dataType: "json",

                         success: function (response) {

                             alert(response);

//I want to assign the response value into username textbox while the form is loaded

                         },
                         failure: function (response) {
                             alert(response);
                         }
                     });
                 }
             });
        </script>
```

I want the Environement username value to be pasted into the textbox. I'm very basic to webdevelopment.

The issue is I can't able to trace the reason in developer tool.

Comment: `alert("in  success "+response);` in your success function and see your `json` data got from server . try to post that as well

Comment: Are you getting the username in alert? or getting an error in alert? Helpful tip: Append Success or Error to your alert message. Right now you do not know if the alert came from success or failure.

Comment: @Swati I tried what you said but no alert is popped up in the window. I'm not getting any type both sucess/failure alert/

Comment: check your browser console is there any error ?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I resolved the problem. The issue is c# webmethod should be static and i missed that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write something to call method on page load

```
         $(document).ready(function () {
                 $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: 'WebForm1.aspx/GetStringValue',

                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                     dataType: "json",

                     success: function (response) {
                         $('#username').val(response);
                     },
                     failure: function (response) {
                         alert(response);
                     }
                 });
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define your method as static like ex.

```
[WebMethod]
    public static  string GetStringValue()
    {
        return Environment.UserName;
    }
```

ajax work with it.